# Passing string parameter from laravel blade to js

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade

How can I pass string parameter from laravel blade.php to javascript upon onclick method.Right now I'm able to pass integer parameter but unable to send  string parameter upon onclick.
like onclick=deleteImage({{$image_name}})

Comment: do you want to set it to any input form field or what? can you explain it a bit?

Comment: show us your code how you were able to pass an integer

Comment: want to pass string variable upon javascript onclick method like this onclick($info) from blade.

Comment: able to send integer but not string

Comment: like onclick=deleteImage({{$image_name}})

Comment: you must use quotes around your brackets, so `deleteImage('{{$image_name}}')`

Comment: you can try putting " like this delete("{{$image_name}}")

Comment: Thanks it works.

Comment: No problem dude